# Is there any feature to add/update firebase user name and photo url in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication

Is there anyway to add/update firebase user name and photo url in flutter like we have `UserProfileChangeRqeust()` in native android?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, there is.

After you have received `FirebaseUser`, you can call the `updateProfile()` method on the object to provide the new details.This method will take an input of type `UserUpdateInfo`.

For eg.,

```
FirebaseUser user = await _auth.currentUser();

UserUpdateInfo userUpdateInfo = UserUpdateInfo();

userUpdateInfo.displayName = 'Ayush';
userUpdateInfo.photoUrl = '<my photo url>';

await user.updateProfile(userUpdateInfo);
```

Comment: UserUpdateInfo is deprecated in the latest version of Firebase Auth. Please update the answer.

Answer (score 4):

**UPDATE 2021, FEB**

This is the updated way for changing the users `displayName` and `photoURL`

```
 void updateUserInfo() {
   var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
   user.updateProfile(displayName: "Abel", photoURL: "photoPath").then((value){
      print("Profile has been changed successfully");
      //DO Other compilation here if you want to like setting the state of the app
   }).catchError((e){
      print("There was an error updating profile");
   });
 }
```

you can read more about this on the official firebase flutter doc. [here](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/User/updateProfile.html)

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE MARCH 2022. VERSIONS:**

**`firebase_core: ^1.13.1`**

**`firebase_auth: ^3.3.10`**

```
final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

User? currentUser = await _auth.currentUser;
currentUser?.updateDisplayName("name...");
```

Comment: based on the documentation [here](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/usage/), you should call _auth.currentUser.reload() to really update the profile in real-time.